# Python Question about Files with lists and functions. Please Help. Thank you

Tags: python, list, function, file

1.Define a function that:

-receives the name of the data file as a parameter

-reads the data from the file into 2 lists, a list of names and a list of
attendance

-returns the lists.

2.Define another function which takes both lists as parameters and return the names of students whose attendance was less than 50 percent.

This is what the file contains:

```
Jack,10
Charlie,6
James,9
Daniel,4
Jake,2
```

I am confused how to go about doing the second part of the question as it prints out only the last name Jake and not Daniel. I know its something to do with how I have the return statement positioned. Does anyone know how to fix it?  This is what I have so far:

```
def file(filename):
names = []
attendance = []
with open(filename) as data_file:
    for line in data_file:
        line_data = line.split(',')
        names.append(line_data[0].strip())
        attendance.append(int(line_data[1].strip()))
return names, attendance



def poor_attendance(name, attendance):
  for x in attendance:
    if x < 5:
        w = name[x]
        return w


def main():
names, attendance = file("school.txt")
school = poor_attendance(names, attendance)
print(f"The following students attendance is less than 50 %:\n{school}")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` to read the two lists pairwise so you can return the names that are paired with attendance values less than 50:

```
def poor_attendance(names, attendance):
    return [n for n, a in zip(names, attendance) if a < 50]
```

Comment: You can do the equivalent of `zip` by iterating by index across both lists at once, sort of like how you built them initially.  Check out https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: If you just want to be given the way to write it out, use the code I gave you.  If you're looking for more understanding on how the code works, ask more specific questions.  If you're trying to write it the way the teacher expects you to write it so they don't know you got help, review the material from the teacher, or ask them directly.